# Extend one object with another using lodash

Tags: lodash

I have an object with an array of images (just the ids).

```
   var listOfImages = {
      "number-items": 30,
      "pageCount": 0,
      "ids": {
        0: "image1",
        1: "image2"
      }
    };
```

I also have a collection of images:

```
    var images = {
      "image1": {
        "author": "Marc",
        "size": "40kb"
      },
      "image2": {
        "author": "Anthony",
        "size": "60kb"
      },
      "image3": {
        "author": "Anthony",
        "size": "60kb"
      }
    }; image2,
    ]
```

I would like to combine them all so having something like this:

```
var extendedListOfImages = {
  "number-items": 30,
  "pageCount": 0,
  "ids": {
    0: {"id": "image1", "author": "Marc", "size": "40kb"},
    1: {"id": "image2", "author": "Anthony", "size": "60kb"}
  }
};
```

This is my code:
https://jsbin.com/pamofudisa/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New to lodash so I would appreciate a better solution if possible.
My solution right now:

```
  var listOfImages = {
  "number-items": 30,
  "pageCount": 0,
  "ids": {
    0: "image1",
    1: "image2"
  }
};
var images = {
  "image1": {
    "author": "Marc",
    "size": "40kb"
  },
  "image2": {
    "author": "Anthony",
    "size": "60kb"
  },
  "image3": {
    "author": "Anthony",
    "size": "60kb"
  }
};

myIds = _.keyBy(listOfImages.ids);
_.map(myIds, function(key, value){
  myIds[key]= images[key];
});
listOfImages.ids=myIds;
console.log(listOfImages);
```

The code in jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/qesuyewuza/1/edit?html,js,console,output